# C - Convert char array to image

Tags: c, compilation, dependencies, include

I'm trying to package a few images within my C code to avoid having to distribute image with the compiled binary, to increase portability.

I've used `xxd -i` in the Linux terminal to create the following char array:

```
unsigned char node_png[] = {
  0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d,
  0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x19,
  0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc4, 0xe9, 0x85, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x09, 0x70, 0x48, 0x59, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b,
  0x13, 0x01, 0x00, 0x9a, 0x9c, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0xfa, 0x69, 0x54,
  0x58, 0x74, 0x58, 0x4d, 0x4c, 0x3a, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x2e, 0x61, 0x64,
  0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x3c, 0x3f, 0x78, 0x70, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x62, 0x65,
  0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x3d, 0x22, 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf, 0x22, 0x20, 0x69, 0x64,
  0x3d, 0x22, 0x57, 0x35, 0x4d, 0x30, 0x4d, 0x70, 0x43, 0x65, 0x68, 0x69,
  0x48, 0x7a, 0x72, 0x65, 0x53, 0x7a, 0x4e, 0x54, 0x63, 0x7a, 0x6b, 0x63,
  0x39, 0x64, 0x22, 0x3f, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x78, 0x3a, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70,
  0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x78,
  0x3d, 0x22, 0x61, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x6d,
  0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x2f, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x3a, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x74,
  0x6b, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x41, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x20, 0x58, 0x4d, 0x50,
  0x20, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x35, 0x2e, 0x36, 0x2d, 0x63, 0x31,
  0x34, 0x35, 0x20, 0x37, 0x39, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x36, 0x33, 0x34, 0x39, 0x39,
  0x2c, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x38, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x38, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x33,
  0x2d, 0x31, 0x36, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x30, 0x3a, 0x32, 0x32, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20,
  0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66,
  0x3a, 0x52, 0x44, 0x46, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x72,
  0x64, 0x66, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x77,
  0x77, 0x77, 0x2e, 0x77, 0x33, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x67, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x39,
  0x39, 0x39, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x32, 0x2f, 0x32, 0x32, 0x2d, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66,
  0x2d, 0x73, 0x79, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x61, 0x78, 0x2d, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x23, 0x22,
  0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x44, 0x65, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72,
  0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x61,
  0x62, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e,
  0x73, 0x3a, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3a,
  0x2f, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x2e, 0x61, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x63,
  0x6f, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0x78, 0x61, 0x70, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2f, 0x22,
  0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x64, 0x63, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x68,
  0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x75, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x2e, 0x6f,
  0x72, 0x67, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x63, 0x2f, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e,
  0x74, 0x73, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x2f, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c,
  0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x70, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x70,
  0x3d, 0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x2e,
  0x61, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x68,
  0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2f,
  0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x4d,
  0x4d, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x73,
  0x2e, 0x61, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0x78,
  0x61, 0x70, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2f, 0x6d, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0x22, 0x20,
  0x78, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x3a, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3d,
  0x22, 0x68, 0x74, 0x74, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x2f, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x2e, 0x61,
  0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x2f, 0x78, 0x61, 0x70,
  0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x2f, 0x73, 0x54, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x52,
  0x65, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x72, 0x63, 0x65, 0x45, 0x76, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74,
  0x23, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x43, 0x72, 0x65, 0x61, 0x74,
  0x6f, 0x72, 0x54, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x41, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62,
  0x65, 0x20, 0x50, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x20,
  0x43, 0x43, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x39, 0x20, 0x28, 0x57, 0x69, 0x6e,
  0x64, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x73, 0x29, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x43,
  0x72, 0x65, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x44, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x32,
  0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x34, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35,
  0x3a, 0x32, 0x37, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x31, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x31, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30,
  0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x4d, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x69, 0x66, 0x79,
  0x44, 0x61, 0x74, 0x65, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2d, 0x30,
  0x34, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3a, 0x32,
  0x31, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x31, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70,
  0x3a, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61, 0x44, 0x61, 0x74,
  0x65, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x34, 0x2d, 0x31,
  0x31, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3a, 0x32, 0x31, 0x2b, 0x30,
  0x31, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20, 0x64, 0x63, 0x3a, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x72,
  0x6d, 0x61, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x67, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x70,
  0x6e, 0x67, 0x22, 0x20, 0x70, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f,
  0x70, 0x3a, 0x43, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x4d, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x65, 0x3d,
  0x22, 0x33, 0x22, 0x20, 0x70, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f,
  0x70, 0x3a, 0x49, 0x43, 0x43, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x66, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x65,
  0x3d, 0x22, 0x73, 0x52, 0x47, 0x42, 0x20, 0x49, 0x45, 0x43, 0x36, 0x31,
  0x39, 0x36, 0x36, 0x2d, 0x32, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70,
  0x4d, 0x4d, 0x3a, 0x49, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x65, 0x49,
  0x44, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x2e, 0x69, 0x69, 0x64, 0x3a, 0x34,
  0x35, 0x39, 0x65, 0x62, 0x63, 0x65, 0x30, 0x2d, 0x39, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33,
  0x2d, 0x65, 0x38, 0x34, 0x37, 0x2d, 0x62, 0x66, 0x66, 0x62, 0x2d, 0x63,
  0x62, 0x38, 0x66, 0x61, 0x32, 0x64, 0x66, 0x39, 0x30, 0x36, 0x30, 0x22,
  0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x4d, 0x3a, 0x44, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x75, 0x6d,
  0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x49, 0x44, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x61, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65,
  0x3a, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x69, 0x64, 0x3a, 0x70, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f,
  0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x3a, 0x65, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x36, 0x38, 0x31,
  0x39, 0x2d, 0x39, 0x62, 0x35, 0x39, 0x2d, 0x33, 0x38, 0x34, 0x30, 0x2d,
  0x62, 0x62, 0x38, 0x37, 0x2d, 0x65, 0x31, 0x61, 0x36, 0x62, 0x32, 0x39,
  0x36, 0x62, 0x31, 0x61, 0x36, 0x22, 0x20, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x4d,
  0x3a, 0x4f, 0x72, 0x69, 0x67, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x44, 0x6f, 0x63,
  0x75, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x49, 0x44, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70,
  0x2e, 0x64, 0x69, 0x64, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x32, 0x64, 0x38, 0x34,
  0x37, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x37, 0x34, 0x63, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x66, 0x34, 0x66, 0x2d,
  0x62, 0x63, 0x62, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x65, 0x32, 0x36, 0x31, 0x32, 0x63, 0x33,
  0x61, 0x35, 0x66, 0x34, 0x30, 0x22, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70,
  0x4d, 0x4d, 0x3a, 0x48, 0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x79, 0x3e, 0x20,
  0x3c, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x53, 0x65, 0x71, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x72,
  0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a,
  0x61, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x63, 0x72, 0x65, 0x61,
  0x74, 0x65, 0x64, 0x22, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x69,
  0x6e, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x65, 0x49, 0x44, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x78,
  0x6d, 0x70, 0x2e, 0x69, 0x69, 0x64, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x32, 0x64,
  0x38, 0x34, 0x37, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x37, 0x34, 0x63, 0x2d, 0x38, 0x66, 0x34,
  0x66, 0x2d, 0x62, 0x63, 0x62, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x65, 0x32, 0x36, 0x31, 0x32,
  0x63, 0x33, 0x61, 0x35, 0x66, 0x34, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45,
  0x76, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x77, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32,
  0x30, 0x2d, 0x30, 0x34, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x32,
  0x37, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x31, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x31, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20,
  0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x66, 0x74, 0x77, 0x61,
  0x72, 0x65, 0x41, 0x67, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x41, 0x64, 0x6f,
  0x62, 0x65, 0x20, 0x50, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x70,
  0x20, 0x43, 0x43, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x39, 0x20, 0x28, 0x57, 0x69,
  0x6e, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x73, 0x29, 0x22, 0x2f, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x72,
  0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a,
  0x61, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x73, 0x61, 0x76, 0x65,
  0x64, 0x22, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x73,
  0x74, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x65, 0x49, 0x44, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70,
  0x2e, 0x69, 0x69, 0x64, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x35, 0x39, 0x65, 0x62, 0x63, 0x65,
  0x30, 0x2d, 0x39, 0x30, 0x33, 0x33, 0x2d, 0x65, 0x38, 0x34, 0x37, 0x2d,
  0x62, 0x66, 0x66, 0x62, 0x2d, 0x63, 0x62, 0x38, 0x66, 0x61, 0x32, 0x64,
  0x66, 0x39, 0x30, 0x36, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74,
  0x3a, 0x77, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x32, 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2d,
  0x30, 0x34, 0x2d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x54, 0x31, 0x35, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x33, 0x3a,
  0x32, 0x31, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x31, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x30, 0x22, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74,
  0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x66, 0x74, 0x77, 0x61, 0x72, 0x65,
  0x41, 0x67, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x41, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x65,
  0x20, 0x50, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x20, 0x43,
  0x43, 0x20, 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x39, 0x20, 0x28, 0x57, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x64,
  0x6f, 0x77, 0x73, 0x29, 0x22, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x45, 0x76, 0x74, 0x3a,
  0x63, 0x68, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x65, 0x64, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x2f, 0x22, 0x2f,
  0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x53, 0x65, 0x71, 0x3e,
  0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x4d, 0x3a, 0x48, 0x69, 0x73,
  0x74, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x79, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66, 0x3a,
  0x44, 0x65, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72, 0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3e,
  0x20, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x66, 0x3a, 0x52, 0x44, 0x46, 0x3e, 0x20,
  0x3c, 0x2f, 0x78, 0x3a, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x74, 0x61, 0x3e,
  0x20, 0x3c, 0x3f, 0x78, 0x70, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x65,
  0x6e, 0x64, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x72, 0x22, 0x3f, 0x3e, 0xdd, 0x6e, 0x4f, 0x3f,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xcf, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x48, 0x89, 0xed, 0x94,
  0xcd, 0x6b, 0x9c, 0x55, 0x14, 0xc6, 0x7f, 0xe7, 0x7e, 0xbd, 0x33, 0xf3,
  0x26, 0x13, 0xe3, 0x24, 0x7e, 0x44, 0x5b, 0xa8, 0xa8, 0x5b, 0x51, 0xdc,
  0x29, 0x52, 0xe8, 0x4a, 0x28, 0x6e, 0x44, 0x17, 0x42, 0x37, 0xba, 0xee,
  0x5f, 0x50, 0x17, 0xba, 0xf2, 0x1f, 0xe8, 0x4e, 0xe8, 0xce, 0xa5, 0x42,
  0xf7, 0xc5, 0x8d, 0x88, 0x68, 0xa1, 0x2e, 0x94, 0x4a, 0x55, 0x88, 0xda,
  0x98, 0x34, 0x99, 0xaf, 0x64, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xbc, 0x33, 0xef, 0x7b, 0xef,
  0x71, 0x31, 0x69, 0x70, 0x2a, 0x15, 0x34, 0x63, 0x17, 0xe2, 0xb3, 0x3d,
  0xf7, 0x3e, 0xbf, 0x73, 0x9e, 0xcb, 0x3d, 0xf2, 0xe6, 0xc5, 0xf7, 0xdf,
  0x95, 0xe1, 0xc1, 0x45, 0x99, 0xee, 0x47, 0x15, 0x53, 0xb2, 0x00, 0x59,
  0x6b, 0xc8, 0x6d, 0x74, 0x5b, 0x9d, 0xd2, 0xed, 0x49, 0xe3, 0x43, 0x67,
  0x8a, 0xe1, 0x7b, 0xda, 0x7a, 0xca, 0xc6, 0x87, 0xce, 0x20, 0xe5, 0xc9,
  0x19, 0x22, 0x50, 0xa9, 0xb2, 0xa9, 0x39, 0x53, 0xfb, 0x0d, 0x8d, 0xad,
  0x1b, 0x97, 0x9c, 0x8e, 0xba, 0x3d, 0x7d, 0xf6, 0xd5, 0x75, 0x7d, 0xe1,
  0x2c, 0x7a, 0x78, 0xf2, 0x29, 0x9c, 0x81, 0x18, 0xe1, 0xcb, 0x0e, 0xac,
  0x1f, 0xc0, 0xd3, 0xe5, 0xb5, 0x3d, 0x87, 0x31, 0x15, 0xe5, 0x04, 0x86,
  0xc0, 0xe8, 0xe4, 0x10, 0x0c, 0x90, 0x20, 0x2f, 0xc1, 0xc7, 0x09, 0x49,
  0x5c, 0x74, 0x88, 0x08, 0x3a, 0x2b, 0x90, 0x16, 0x00, 0x61, 0xe6, 0x63,
  0x14, 0x66, 0xc6, 0x88, 0x59, 0x90, 0xed, 0x5f, 0xea, 0x7f, 0xc8, 0xdf,
  0x84, 0xe8, 0x83, 0x80, 0x3c, 0x00, 0xfd, 0x17, 0x21, 0xff, 0xe2, 0xdb,
  0xb8, 0x39, 0xc8, 0x22, 0x40, 0x47, 0x3e, 0x32, 0x0f, 0xd1, 0xd9, 0xea,
  0x74, 0x73, 0xc8, 0x7f, 0x2e, 0x03, 0x44, 0xa8, 0x0c, 0x24, 0x04, 0x41,
  0x8f, 0x6c, 0xc5, 0x82, 0x07, 0xec, 0x82, 0x20, 0x02, 0xf1, 0x08, 0x02,
  0x8a, 0xa3, 0xb1, 0x86, 0x6c, 0x5f, 0xc7, 0xf4, 0x6e, 0x41, 0x8a, 0x7f,
  0xba, 0x33, 0x3b, 0x76, 0x7f, 0xdd, 0x5b, 0x57, 0x14, 0x67, 0x85, 0x57,
  0xa8, 0xd1, 0xdd, 0xfb, 0x85, 0x43, 0xb7, 0xae, 0xce, 0x84, 0xfa, 0x23,
  0xb1, 0xe8, 0x22, 0x83, 0xdb, 0xf7, 0xd9, 0x97, 0x33, 0x0b, 0x11, 0x99,
  0xcb, 0x59, 0x01, 0xd5, 0xa3, 0xda, 0x1f, 0x2a, 0xc6, 0x1a, 0x0e, 0x7a,
  0x23, 0x5a, 0x4d, 0xcb, 0x33, 0xe7, 0x73, 0x3e, 0xfb, 0x24, 0x5b, 0x77,
  0x55, 0x39, 0xb9, 0x61, 0x43, 0xfe, 0x62, 0xf2, 0x0d, 0xe4, 0x9e, 0x96,
  0xef, 0x1a, 0xd5, 0xeb, 0x19, 0x56, 0xac, 0x2a, 0xe9, 0xd8, 0x4d, 0x30,
  0x1a, 0x53, 0x94, 0x71, 0x31, 0x99, 0x6b, 0x40, 0x45, 0xa8, 0xaf, 0x35,
  0x89, 0xb5, 0xc0, 0xe6, 0xb7, 0x7d, 0x52, 0x4a, 0x37, 0xdd, 0xb4, 0x2c,
  0x5e, 0x5b, 0x76, 0xcd, 0xd7, 0xa7, 0x71, 0x1a, 0xc4, 0x98, 0x68, 0xad,
  0x45, 0x14, 0x74, 0x96, 0x83, 0x64, 0x99, 0xef, 0x6c, 0xfd, 0xba, 0x7b,
  0xb6, 0xdd, 0xeb, 0xbf, 0x1d, 0x7c, 0x38, 0x8e, 0x24, 0x56, 0x15, 0x6b,
  0x6b, 0x0f, 0x5f, 0x39, 0xbd, 0xf1, 0xd8, 0xa7, 0x45, 0x31, 0x59, 0x4f,
  0x9a, 0x74, 0x86, 0x12, 0xc2, 0x92, 0xe5, 0x4e, 0x7b, 0xdf, 0xb6, 0xbf,
  0xea, 0x97, 0xf5, 0xd3, 0x4b, 0x57, 0x9d, 0x88, 0xec, 0x24, 0x4d, 0x97,
  0x43, 0x08, 0x18, 0x11, 0x06, 0x83, 0x43, 0x90, 0xd9, 0x14, 0x21, 0x04,
  0xca, 0xa2, 0xe0, 0xd6, 0x0f, 0x3f, 0x9d, 0x1a, 0x8c, 0x46, 0x52, 0xcb,
  0xc2, 0x71, 0x44, 0xb1, 0x8a, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xce, 0xee, 0x8f, 0x31, 0xc5,
  0x8f, 0x5a, 0x2b, 0xab, 0x14, 0x93, 0x31, 0x22, 0x06, 0x2b, 0xb0, 0xe4,
  0x57, 0x18, 0x15, 0x25, 0xf5, 0x96, 0xe0, 0x1c, 0x38, 0x55, 0xa5, 0x56,
  0x0b, 0xf4, 0xfb, 0x03, 0xfa, 0xed, 0x01, 0xb7, 0xb7, 0x77, 0x88, 0x5e,
  0xd1, 0x32, 0x91, 0xaf, 0x36, 0x69, 0xd5, 0xeb, 0x3c, 0xf9, 0xc4, 0xa3,
  0xe7, 0xb1, 0x16, 0x51, 0x45, 0x55, 0xf1, 0xde, 0xd3, 0xe9, 0xf4, 0xe8,
  0xee, 0xef, 0xbf, 0xf1, 0xdd, 0xf7, 0x9b, 0x1f, 0x58, 0xbb, 0x8d, 0x93,
  0x8a, 0x28, 0x86, 0xa0, 0x15, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x6d, 0x10, 0x4b, 0xc5, 0x1a,
  0x8f, 0xaa, 0x62, 0x9f, 0x7f, 0xf9, 0x1c, 0xc5, 0xb0, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0xeb,
  0x37, 0x69, 0xdf, 0xe9, 0xe1, 0x33, 0xef, 0xf1, 0x52, 0xd7, 0x2a, 0xa5,
  0xb0, 0x9c, 0x67, 0xcb, 0xcd, 0xc6, 0xa5, 0x20, 0xf6, 0x82, 0xcf, 0x02,
  0xd6, 0x1a, 0xbc, 0x73, 0x78, 0xef, 0xf0, 0x21, 0xa3, 0x9c, 0x16, 0x8f,
  0xa3, 0x34, 0x14, 0xf7, 0x85, 0x35, 0x29, 0x21, 0x36, 0xb7, 0x1a, 0xe9,
  0xee, 0xee, 0xc4, 0xd1, 0xf0, 0x37, 0x96, 0x1a, 0x39, 0x6e, 0x39, 0x47,
  0x9e, 0x3b, 0xf7, 0x16, 0xe3, 0xe1, 0x84, 0x62, 0x3c, 0x21, 0x64, 0x1e,
  0x85, 0x77, 0x70, 0xe6, 0x82, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0x6d, 0x9d, 0x5d, 0xf5, 0x21,
  0xbc, 0xa4, 0x31, 0x1d, 0x82, 0x96, 0xdc, 0xfd, 0xc8, 0x0a, 0xce, 0x3b,
  0x4d, 0x29, 0xda, 0xf1, 0x78, 0xba, 0x82, 0xc8, 0xe7, 0x82, 0x76, 0x11,
  0xd9, 0x10, 0x8d, 0x1f, 0x8b, 0xc6, 0xcb, 0x29, 0x25, 0x9c, 0xb5, 0xd8,
  0xac, 0xc6, 0xef, 0xfe, 0x45, 0x42, 0xdf, 0x5c, 0x68, 0x68, 0xc7, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0xae, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82
};
unsigned int node_png_len = 2339;
```

I'd like to convert this back to a .png like it originally was but, unless I'm missing something, I'm really struggling to find a direct answer to this question anywhere. I am using GTK so need to get the image into GdkPixbuf format eventually. How would I go about this?

I've tried to use `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ()`, however have only ended up with garbled mess, unless I've misunderstood the arguments?

Is this the way to be going about achieving this, or is there a better way of packaging an image with my binary? Thanks.

Comment: `GdkPixbuf` is uncompressed image, png is. so first you need to decompress png

Comment: @IłyaBursov Surely once it's been compressed it's still just an image though? I just need to create a GdkPixbuf from this data, however having tried to use `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data ()` I just get garbled nonsense?

Comment: it is not an image in terms of gdk

Comment: I dont know anything about .png format or Gdk ,, but you could be having endianess issues if you're `xxd`ing the raw data in bytes directly to a byte array.

Comment: @yano Glib does the byte order job.